# Nuget on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I use Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and I'm trying to install **mvcScaffolding** but I'm getting errors. I've tried to set the **ExecutiongPolicy** to **Bypass**, but I'm still getting errors. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
PM> Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process
Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic. Do you want to change the execution policy?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):y

PM> install-package mvcScaffolding
Attempting to resolve dependency 'T4Scaffolding'.
Install-Package : '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
At line:1 char:16
+ install-package <<<<  mvcScaffolding
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], XmlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Comment: That doesn't sound like something you can bypass...  It's saying there is an exception that isn't being handled

Comment: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1790

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reintalling VS2012, Nuget, etc., I've found the solution, to remove the Packages folder.
Thanks. Guillermo.